# Application update removes settings

Tags: c#, installation, settings, inno-setup, application-settings

This is probably something stupid, but when I do an update in my software it doesn't keep the existing application settings.

On each update you have to reset the configuration.  How do I get around that?

The settings are set to User scope, the installation is created with an ISS script (Inno Setup)

I hope someone has the answer got quite a lot of unhappy customers :(

Comment: how is your application settings defined?

Comment: in Visual Studio, settings "tab" and the names and values are set there, then on the app there is a config form that saves the settings.

Comment: I believe the user settings are for a specific version of the application.  If you are changing the Assembly Version, this is probably causing it to not see the previous version's settings.  Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: There is an `Upgrade` method on the Settings class.  Perhaps you need to call this on first run after an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Boolean` setting for `CallUpgrade` or something similar

Set it to `true` by `default`

Then call something like:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

That should only run once if the program has updated, since `CallUpgrade` will be set to true again.

I don't know how much might have changed for WPF but that is the WinForms version of it, should be very similar.

Comment: I went with a similar thing of using the registry but your method would be even better. I'll give it a go!